# horizontal partitioning a mysql table with two indices

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning, horizontal-scaling

I have a mysql table that stores user ratings for different items. It has the following fields:

- id (int, pk)
- userId (int)
- itemId (int)
- rating (float)
- timestamp (int)

and following indices:

- (userId, rating): for queries about all items a particular user has rated
- (itemId, rating): for queries about all users that have rated a particular item

This table has over 10 million rows. To make it more scalable, I would like to perform a horizontal partitioning. In particular, I plan to partition the table into 20 tables:

- tbl_rating_by_item_0: store ratings whose itemId ending with 0
- tbl_rating_by_item_1: store ratings whose itemId ending with 1
- ......
- tbl_rating_by_item_9: store ratings whose itemId ending with 9

and

- tbl_rating_by_user_0: store ratings whose userId ending with 0
- tbl_rating_by_user_1: store ratings whose userId ending with 1
- ......
- tbl_rating_by_user_9: store ratings whose userId ending with 9

The idea is when querying by itemId we read from tbl_rating_by_item_itemId and when querying by userId we read from tbl_rating_by_user_userId. The drawback is whenever I want to insert or delete a rating, I need to insert into or delete from two tables.

Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried indexing? Creating two composite indexes

```
 INDEX name1 (rating,userid)
 INDEX name2 (rating,itemId)
```

may help increase in performance.

Also consider table partitioning. Have a look at [Mysql able partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html)
This is better than physically creating two separate tables.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the post I used two composite indexes. The reason I need to partition the table physically is that my site is running on an app engine which only allows 10 million rows for a table.